# how to check object property exists in array of object, find repeated property in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, object

I would like to know how to compare the object value exists in

the array of objects, then check if it is repeated and return true or false in javascript

for example,
if the object value exists in `mode` property array object,

then check the `valueid` property in `itemarray` has duplicates

conditions to check:

`if object has same valueid, mode value is FI/FD(different no duplicates) then return false`

`if object has same valueid, mode value is SE/SA then return true`

`if object has same valueid, mode has same/duplicates then return true`

```
var obj={
   service: "SE",
   sales: "SA",
   finance: "FI",
   others: "FD"
}

var itemarray=[ 
  {name: "nemo", valueid: "abc", mode: "SE" },
  {name: "mike", valueid: "xyz", mode: "FI" },
  {name: "jim", valueid: "xyz",  mode: "FD" },
  {name: "jim", valueid: "mno",  mode: "SA" }
]



Expected Result
// same valueid, mode value is FI/FD(different no duplicates)
false


I tried
function checkRepeatedValues(){
  const getValues = itemarray.map(elm => elm.valueid);
    if (itemArray.length !== new Set(getValues).size) {
      return true;
    } else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: The logic is inconsistent here. In your question, you say if the same 'valueid' but different 'mode' values, then false should be returned, but then in your expected result, you say the expected output is true by the exact same logic?

Comment: @JackBashford thanks for reply, updated the answer, yes should return false

Comment: As per your question, `if object has same/duplicate valueid` - Then why we are considering it while comparing ? as it will not make any impact.